# Can A Fish Leap Over A Mountain?

Tags: biology

This question is based off a Pokedex entry for Magikarp, which states that a Magikarp that has lived for many years can use Splash to leap over a mountain. So, essentially, we have a *fish* somehow capable of unleashing enough kinetic force to launch itself over a mountain. My question is, **Can A Fish Truly Leap A Mountain?**

Is this even possible? If not, is it even plausible? What adaptations would be required for a fish to launch itself over a mountain, and why on Earth would it adapt such a capability?

Comment: An artillery shell can't clear a mountain. Or maybe it can. But either way, you get the picture.

Comment: There are lots of underwater mountains. :)

Comment: Only if the fish is a [special kind of fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_fish) and the mountain is a very small itsy-bitsy really tiny mountain.

Comment: @alex flying fish can't fly once their tails leave contact with the water.

Comment: Just a side note: Magikarp is based on an old Chinese legend [鲤跃龙门: Carp jumps over the Dragon Gate] about [a carp transforming into a dragon](http://www.confuciusinstitute.ac.uk/carp-leaping-over-the-dragon-gate-mystery-revealed/). I am not sure how many mythological carps managed to become dragons. Perhaps no more than one.

Comment: Theoretically, It would depend on the gravity and magnetic field of the planet or moon, the height of the mountain and the amount of kinetic energy such an animal can produce in burst. But at the gravity levels required for a fish of 1 meter to - for example - jump over something 100 times larger than itself, the gravity would have to be so low that the planet(oid) would likely have no atmosphere. The gravity of the moon is "only" 6 times lower than Earth and yet it cannot retain a viable atmosphere.

Answer (score 11):

> "it is pathetically weak. Even in the heat of battle it will do nothing but flop around."

They are however intelligent, capable of learning and have hitherto unexplored sensory subtlety. Their extremely long, delicate [barbels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbel_(anatomy)) are very susceptible to changes in the weather. They know when a storm is coming, when the air pressure changes, when a static charge is in the air above their watery home.

They twitch in anticipation when they sense this is coming:

[image]

<sup>Dr. Joseph Golden, NOAA - Public domain 2021, via Wikipedia</sup>

Not just that, but their refined sensibilities guide them to time their entry into the spout - at just the right angle, and with just the correct oomph to get lifted up.

Once in, the most extreme theme-park ride looks like a toddler's playground in comparison, but they somehow, following some instinct or higher sense of purpose, endure the currents, feeling their way, find just the correct moment to flick their tails and to exit - flinging them over the desired peak. Their fate on landing is nothing less than a miracle, they always seem to land in something wet - not always clean and sanitary, but a soft-ish landing nonetheless. They may not come-up smelling of the proverbial rose, but they always come-up alive and wriggling with the energies of their transformation growing within.

Comment: Intelligent Sharknado!  Now I have seen everything!

Comment: Interesting....tornado-launched fish? Intriguing idea....

Answer (score 5):

If the fish chooses the right place, it can leap over the North American Continental Divide.  For instance, starting in the Pacific it swims up the Columbia River, makes a right turn at the Snake, then up Pacific Creek.  Jump into Atlantic Creek, follow it downstream to the Yellowstone, Missouri, & Mississippi Rivers, and swim into the Gulf of Mexico: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Ocean_Pass

The fish can do the same thing via Canada, ending up in Hudson Bay: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_Creek https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Committee%27s_Punch_Bowl

Comment: Great point, very clever, but not quite what I'm looking for. Thanks though!

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that if you were to place a couple kiddie pools on either side of [Jing Shan](https://www.elitereaders.com/jingshan-smallest-mountain-china-conquered-1step/) in Shouguang a leaping fish could easily saltate over its lofty 6000 dmm peak.

[image]

Comment: Very good point! So, it'd take some doing, but it is possible to leap over a mountain peak, so why not a mountain?

Comment: @Alendyias -- As I understand it, Jing Shan ***ìs*** the mountain, and yeah, it only rises two feet or so above the agricultural field it resides in! If the story about the mountain is true, they apparently tried to dig down to determine if it's just a big rock or what. I think they got down to like 150 feet or so, gave up digging, and just decided to call it a mountain! Other contenders for small mountains, Mt Wycheproof in Australia, and Rockall in the UK might be a bit tall to leap over!

Comment: Oh, so it's perfectly possible, depending on the mountain! Thank you for clarifying, it made my day to hear about Jing Shan!

Comment: @Alendyias -- You got it! If you can't leap the mountain, find a leapable mountain!

Answer (score 4):

In stormy weather and with some luck, this fish could take off and land on the other side ?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFQ7AEsl60M
[image]

Comment: Hmmm.....so a flying fish, surfing over a mountain on the winds of a storm? That would be quite the feat!

Answer (score 2):

## The fish must have incredible lungs

<sup>I'd also recommend a helmet, goggles, and not jumping in the first place.</sup>

You asked about biology, and I agree that generating the required kinetic force is a critical challenge, but if we assume that "plausibility" also requires the fish to survive the journey, we must take into account the fish's regular needs during the trip, the most urgent of which may be air. After all, most fish cannot breathe out of water.

### Upper limits on travel distance

Let's start by studying familiar examples.

- How long can you hold your breath? Perhaps 60 seconds?
- What is the fastest means of transportation reasonably available to you?
- How far will that transpo take you in 60 seconds?

Spacetime<sup>1</sup> says `D = v * t`.

WP says [bullet-trains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-speed_rail) travel ~120-160mph.

That's only 2.6667 miles.

I believe the Peregrine Falcon is the fastest animal on Earth. WP says [Peregrine Falcons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peregrine_falcon) can reach 200mph.

That's only 3.333 miles.

### Trip length and mountain size

Now, let's consider the requirements of the fish's journey.

- How far is a journey over a mountain?

I believe that's called the "overland distance." It's neither the height of the mountain, nor its footprint, but the length of the shortest curved line segment that connects two points on opposite sides of the base of the mountain, and passing through a point at the top. Imagine building a giant arch over the mountain, but it's a hollow tube, and this fish will travel along it like one of those vacuum tubes that banks use at the drive-thru.

You didn't specify a mountain, and I'm not going to waste your time with [Garth Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Englishman_who_Went_up_a_Hill_but_Came_down_a_Mountain)-style parsing. We just want to guesstimate how many monster trucks your Piscine Knievel can fit in the area under its projected path, so we can stick with basic trig. For a more realistic answer, I think you need someone who can do ballistics.<sup>2</sup>

The distance "over" a triangle is basically the combined lengths of two of its sides.

For simplicity, let's assume the fish's points of departure and arrival are both in bodies of water, and that both bodies have the same elevation, i.e. the fish is not jumping from a mountain lake down into the ocean, or vice-versa. Which is to say: our triangle is an [isosceles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_triangle) triangle.

So, let's take that "awesome" 3⅓-miles figure and divide it by two: 1⅔ miles.

The height of an isosceles triangle is easy to calculate, but it depends on how wide the triangle is at the bottom. Here are some sample values (in filthy Imperial miles):

| Base | Height | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.166 | 1.66 | 10x taller than wide |
| 1.666 | 1.44 | Equilateral |
| 3.327 | 0.10 | Fattest possible before height less than than 0.1 |

Let's compare our biggest height to real mountains to get a feel for the population of mountains that could be jumped by a *human* holding their breath while flying at 200mph.

WP has a [list of mountains by elevation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mountains_by_elevation).

[Mount Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Discovery) has an elevation of 8,796 feet, which is precisely what my not-very-careful-about-significant-digits math gave me for a mountain 1.666 miles tall.

### Fish lungs

A human can hold their breath for about a minute or two, although a few people have lasted [substantially longer](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/longest-time-breath-held-voluntarily-(male)).

Humans have GBLs<sup>3</sup>, but we also have big oxygen needs.

I am not a fish expert<sup>4</sup>, but the googs says there's a [fish that can hold its breath for 4 minutes](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2019/06/spotted-first-time-fish-holding-its-breath-underwater).

So I guess we need to do all that math again, because that is a lot longer than a dumb human!

- 4 minutes @ 200mph = 13.3332 miles
- side of isosceles triangle = 6⅔ miles
- ~max height of triangle = 6⅔ miles (that's convenient)

That works out to a mountain with elevation 35,200 feet, which is over a mile taller than Everest (29,029ft).

Which brings me to my final point:

## Fish needs a helmet

What goes up must come down.<sup>[citation needed]</sup>

At the conclusion of this giant leap for fish-kind, your fish will hit the water with essentially the same force it used at launch.

Fish tend to be aerodynamic<sup>5</sup>, so I would not expect air resistance to contribute much deceleration to counter the acceleration due to gravity.

Fish tend to move forwards. Unless your fish reorients itself in-flight, it will hit the water face-first.

Water is a fluid, but it can still hurt if you're traveling fast enough. How much will this hurt?

- Sadly, this [question on Physics SO](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/135685/at-what-speed-would-you-die-upon-impact-with-water) has only a couple of answers, and both are unsatisfying.
- [Crude googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=hitting+water+at+200+mph) suggests that a human is essentially flash-tenderized by collision with water at just 130mph<sup>6</sup>.
- I [*also*](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=9964836&sid=58bc9c99e3e60123738a0aa5c9cb91e4#p9964836) read the *Worst Case Scenario Survival Handbook*, so I can tell you that high-speed collision can force water to enter body orifices at deadly pressures.
- A [post further down](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=9964833&sid=58bc9c99e3e60123738a0aa5c9cb91e4#p9964833) quotes a Coast Guard officer describing the effect of jumping off the Golden Gate Bridge (hitting at ~75mph) thus:

  > It's as if someone took an eggbeater to the organs of the body and ground everything up.

So, I think your fish will need some serious protection to survive a face-first impact, even considering the narrower cross-section, if for no other reason than [the mouth of most fish is on the front](https://www.leisurepro.com/blog/explore-the-blue/fish-identification-guide-fish-anatomy-part-ii/) (skip down to "Mouth Positions").

---

<sup>1</sup> Spacetime of the flattish sort commonly found in pubs and near mountains.

<sup>2</sup> I no calculus, am calcu-loser.

<sup>3</sup> Great Big Lungs. What were you expecting?

<sup>4</sup> Rather, the fish-related areas of my expertise do not encompass their respiratory systems.

<sup>5</sup> This makes them tastier.

<sup>6</sup> I officially call dibs on Ceviche Slam™️, a restaurant where they drop your uncooked steak from orbit into a vat of lime juice, simultaneously flash-cooking and -tenderizing it.

Comment: Thanks for covering the biological aspect of the question, Tom! I appreciate your thorough answer, and your calculations. Out of curiosity, how does fish being aerodynamic make them tastier?

Comment: How does it _not_?